# Why can't I assign uint16 array to array vector in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point, type-conversion

I run the following code:

```
    colored = np.empty((299, 299, 3), dtype=float) # dtype=`uint16` doesn't work too!
    colored[:, :, 0] = image
    colored[:, :, 1] = image
    colored[:, :, 2] = image
```

If I plot `image` (2 dimensional array of `uint16`), I can see the correct picture. But if I plot `colored` array then I get the following trash image:

[image]

I plot with the following code:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.imshow(colored, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
```

When I plot `image` it works. When I plot `colored` it doesn't. What's going on here and how can I fix that?

Comment: What plot command are you using?  Do the numbers look right ?

Comment: I use `plt.imshow(colored, cmap='gray')`. Numbers look right! So, something's wrong with plot function...

Comment: But I'm trying to plot `colored` and it should be array of `float`. When I'm plotting `image` (array of `uint16`) by the same way, it works!

Comment: How about `imshow(colored[:,:,0])`?  When creating the 3d array, are you normalizing the values.  `imshow` says the values should be in the 0.0 to 1.0 range.

Comment: Both 2D array and 3D array of 0.0-1.0 values work fine. But I thought that `imshow` can be used with 3-color images with values 0..255...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the array passed to imshow is 3-dimensional and has floating-point dtype,
`plt.show()` calls [this piece of code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/c2f91c50fd6dd9338d1aa23dd9770992f02a9147#diff-1e55f4519a5f7ba6102dc510b66030d1R262):

```
if x.ndim == 3:
    ...    
    if xx.dtype.kind == 'f':
        if bytes:
            xx = (xx * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    return xx
```

So the values in `colored` are being multiplied by 255 and then `astype`d to `np.uint8`. 
This happens *before* the values are normalized to the interval `[0, 1]`. You can verify this by putting a print statement in your `matplotlib/cm.py` file:

```
if x.ndim == 3:
    ...    
    if xx.dtype.kind == 'f':
        if bytes:
            print(xx.max())
            xx = (xx * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    return xx
```

and running this script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

maxval = np.iinfo('uint16').max
uint16_image = np.linspace(0, maxval, (16**2)).astype('uint16')
uint16_image = uint16_image.reshape(16, 16)

colored = np.empty(uint16_image.shape + (3,), dtype=float)
colored[:, :, 0] = uint16_image
colored[:, :, 1] = uint16_image
colored[:, :, 2] = uint16_image

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
ax[0].imshow(uint16_image)
ax[1].imshow(colored)
plt.show()
```

which prints

```
65535.0
65535.0
```

and displays
[image]

The moral of the story is that if you pass a 3D float array to `plt.imshow`, the values **must** be between 0 and 1 (or NaN) or else you will likely get (graphical) mojibake.

Comment: Using your example above, what would cause the second plot gradient to be [blank](https://i.imgur.com/7s8nEra.png) aside from the black square in the upper left?

Comment: The difference in behavior is caused by [this change](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10220/files#diff-d7067d23b8918c423e30d4a3c6e13a60R640) to the matplotlib source code. (See [pull 10220](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10220)). At this point in the code the dtype of `self._A` is `float64` so the high is set to 1. `self._A = np.clip(self._A, 0, high)` now clips everything to 0 or 1.